# How to figure out if email obfuscation with JavaScript works?

Tags: javascript, email, obfuscation

I am using a JavaScript function erot13. As it is advised by some articles, this function suppose to obfuscate the email, so the email harvesting bots are not able to extract it from the website.

```
function erot13(s) {
  return (s ? s : this).split("").map(function (_) {
    if (!_.match(/[A-za-z]/)) return _;
    var c = Math.floor(_.charCodeAt(0) / 97);
    var k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 83) % 26 || 26;
    return String.fromCharCode(k + ((c == 0) ? 64 : 96));
  }).join("");
}

function erot13_onload(event) {
  var elements = window.document.querySelectorAll("a[data-erot13]");
  for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    var element = elements[j];
    var email = element.dataset.erot13;
    var overwrite = element.dataset.erot13Overwrite !== undefined;
    if (email !== undefined) {
      element.href = "mailto:" + erot13(email);
      if (overwrite) {
        element.innerHTML = erot13(email);
      }
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", erot13_onload);
```

A step by step process how I implement it looks like this:

1. I place this function in a separate js file and place a script tag in index.html:

```
<script src="erot13.js"></script>
```

2. I go to this website to get the encrypted version of my email:
   https://rot13.com/
3. Finally, I add  tag to my index.html with data-erot13 attribute where I place my encrypted email:

```
<a data-erot13="yvanf.zbpkjavf@tznvy.pbz"><span class="email"></span>Email Me</a>
```

Everything suppose to work fine, but if I inspect my email in the browser I see my real email but not the encrypted version of it. Does that mean the erot13 function does not work? How to figure out is it really encrypted or not for the bots?

Comment: Bots are not supossed to execute javascript and they just take codes as plain text to search for addresses so, that code is "bot safe"... theoretically.

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's just obfuscated. Every bot could deobfuscate it by simply running your js code telling it how to do so. You will only fool those that don't do that, or try simple decodings like rot13 by default.

Comment: @Triby "*Bots are not supossed to execute javascript*" - says who?

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Is it still relevant to use email obfuscation techniques nowadays like I have?

Answer (score 2):

Your method `rot13` is working fine as far as I see it. But by modifying the `element.href` and `element.innerHTML` variables in the function `erot13_onload` you change the DOM.

So, before any JavaScript is executed on your page, the HTML elements will contain the encoded email addresses. When the `load` is executed, your `erot13_onload` function will replace the encoded email address with the real one.

A bot will not be able to see the real email address, unless it can execute JavaScript or detect the encoded email. Then it will see the same output as you do (decoded email address).

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with this site: https://seositecheckup.com/, but whenever I paste my websites url into it to check for a various SEO mistakes, the engine of this website still says, that my email is not obfuscated, even though I have this erot13 function implemented and they themselves recommend to implement this function. Do you have any ideas why it happens like this?